# Passing arrays to functions or a subprocedure

Tags: arrays, vba

I have a quick question regarding coding into vba,  I am trying to write a sorting algorithm into vba.

However I am having trouble passing an integer array into a function.  Is there a way to pass an array into a function?  I believe passing it as a variant is the correct way to do it.

Also is there a way to get the functions return value to pass as an array as well?

Comment: [How to: Pass an Array to a Procedure?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/63y5ksfs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @Omar nice link but not quite VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Chip Pearson's examples](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/passingandreturningarrays.htm) You can pass an array as a parameter

```
Function SumArray(Arr() As Long) As Long
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' SumArray
    ' This sums the elements of Arr and returns
    ' the total.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 
    Dim N As Long
    Dim Total As Long
    For N = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Total = Total + Arr(N)
    Next N
    SumArray = Total
End Function
```

also, return an array as result of a function, eg.

```
Function LoadNumbers(Low As Long, High As Long) As Long()
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Returns an array of Longs, containing
    ' the numbers from Low to High. The 
    ' number of elements in the returned
    ' array will vary depending on the 
    ' values of Low and High.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim ResultArray() As Long
    Dim Ndx As Long
    Dim Val As Long
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Ensure Low <= High
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Low > High Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Resize the array
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ReDim ResultArray(1 To (High - Low + 1))
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Fill the array with values.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Val = Low
    For Ndx = LBound(ResultArray) To UBound(ResultArray)
        ResultArray(Ndx) = Val
        Val = Val + 1
    Next Ndx

    LoadNumbers = ResultArray()

End Function
```

Further info/examples [www.cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/passingandreturningarrays.htm)

Comment: Why are you posting Chip Pearson's code without proper attribution?

Comment: Could you guide me on how to include the proper attribution?  Isn't enough with the link?

Comment: See the following: http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing Since you did include the link I knew that you weren't trying to be misleading, but that is how it might come across. The main point is that if you are quoting a large section of code that someone else wrote it should be clear in the body of the answer and not in a link that not all will follow.

Comment: Thanks @JohnColeman and Omar, I'll pay more attention to this next time.